# Java SimpleDateFormat and compareTo

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I've got a question about SimpleDateFormat class and the java.util.Date's compareto method:

I'm constructing a Date object, then I format, finally I parse the formatted string and compare to the original date.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MMMdd hh:mm:ss SSS");
Date originalDate = new Date();

String s = df.format(originalDate);
Date parsedDate = df.parse(s);

System.out.println("Original date: " + originalDate);
System.out.println("Formatted date: " + s);
System.out.println("originalDate compareTo parsedDate: " + originalDate.compareTo(parsedDate));
```

The result:

> Original date: Mon Jan 25 15:43:23 CET
>   2010 Formatted date: 2010.jan.25
>   03:43:23 868 originalDate compareTo
>   parsedDate: 1

Why I am getting always "1"? Why the original date grater than the parsed date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a 24h related problem, your original date it's 15, so 3PM, while your parsed one is in 12 hours format, this because you used **h** format specifier instead of **H** format specifier. You hour is then turned into the wrong string so you lose precision because when parsed back `03` is considered 3AM. Try with:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MMMdd HH:mm:ss SSS");
```

Comment: Or use a, the AM/PM specifier,

Comment: I just tried the code, it works with **HH** so that was the problem. Of course as suggested, if you need it in 12hour format you can use the AM/PM specifier instead of **HH**

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add the Am/pm marker - `a`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MMMdd hh:mm:ss SSS a");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to merely compare the dates, perhaps using getTime() to compare the two values would be a better idea...